# File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Quickstart Plugin cannot function without it

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services, cordova-plugins

I am getting the warning in the title when I am trying to compile my cordova project.

I am using the cordova push notification plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-gcmpushplugin to try and send push notifications from our server to our app.

I have Google Play Services and Repository installed and up to date.

The project compiles, and installs and launches successfully but this warning worries me.

I do have the file, but I cannot seem to find where I need to put it.

"android-proj/app" and "android-proj/mobile" doesn't mean much to me.

Any suggestions about where I need to put this and why it would not be finding it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep the file inside `cordova-project/platforms/android/` directory. This is where your build.gradle file resides in which the dependencies are recorded and used by the build system, this is where cordova would modify your dependencies hence you require it inside the above path.

Comment: Is this the same for iOS?

Comment: iOS has a plist file instead that needs to be stored in "/platforms/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist"